# JMeter Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter, keystore, jks

Jmeter. I set the path and password to my jks in system.properties. I execute an HTTP request and see an errors in the logs:

```
    2022-04-07 17:22:54,758 ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found

java.lang.NullPointerException: No key(s) found
```

and

```
2022-04-07 17:22:55,257 ERROR o.a.j.u.k.JmeterKeyStore: No var called 'certAlias' found
```

log:

```
2-04-07 17:22:54,738 INFO o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: Configuring Keystore with (preload: 'True', startIndex: 0, endIndex: -1, clientCertAliasVarName: 'certAlias')
2022-04-07 17:22:54,739 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2022-04-07 17:22:54,740 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2022-04-07 17:22:54,741 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: client.jks type JKS
2022-04-07 17:22:54,744 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2022-04-07 17:22:54,758 ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found
java.lang.NullPointerException: No key(s) found
                at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
                at org.apache.jmeter.util.keystore.JmeterKeyStore.load(JmeterKeyStore.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:141) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.configureKeystore(SSLManager.java:309) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig.testStarted(KeystoreConfig.java:99) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig.testStarted(KeystoreConfig.java:63) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:206) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:381) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:819) [?:1.8.0_232]
2022-04-07 17:22:54,765 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2022-04-07 17:22:54,852 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group MyRq REST
2022-04-07 17:22:54,852 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group MyRq REST.
2022-04-07 17:22:54,852 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2022-04-07 17:22:54,853 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=0 delayedStart=false
2022-04-07 17:22:54,863 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2022-04-07 17:22:54,863 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2022-04-07 17:22:55,101 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group MyRq REST 1-1
2022-04-07 17:22:55,182 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Maximum connection retries = 0
2022-04-07 17:22:55,257 ERROR o.a.j.u.k.JmeterKeyStore: No var called 'certAlias' found
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure that your `client.jks` keystore has certificates in it? You can check it by using [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) command like:

   ```
   keytool -list -v /path/to/your/client.jks
   ```

   alternatively you can use a GUI-based tool like [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)
2. `No var called 'certAlias' found` indicates that you're using [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) element and don't have associated [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) pointing to the file holding certificates aliases. If you plan to use one certificate only and not an individual certificate per user - just remove the Keystore Configuration. If you plan to use [multiple certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) - add CSV Data Set Config and set it up to read the CSV file where all certificate aliases will be listed.